# For $P\left(\int_{X_{(n)}}^{1}\frac{1}{\theta^n}e^{-(\theta-1)^{-2}}d\theta>C\right)$, $C >0$, how to get the random variable $X_{(n)}$ to one side?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and for $X_{(n)} = \max\left(X_1, \ldots, X_n\right)$ where $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim Unif(0,1)$ iid. I have that:

$$
P\left(\int_{X_{(n)}}^{1}\frac{1}{\theta^n}e^{-(\theta-1)^{-2}}d\theta>C\right)
$$

for a $C >0$. I would ultimately like to show that

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left(\int_{X_{(n)}}^{1}\frac{1}{\theta^n}e^{-(\theta-1)^{-2}}d\theta>C\right) = 0
$$

However, I am having trouble trying to separate out the stochastic element, $X_{(n)}$ off to one side. Does anyone see anything I can do here? Thanks.

Comment: $X_{(n)}\to 1$ with probability $1$. So, the integral tends to $0$; becomes greater than any $C<1$. Is this not enough?

Comment: $X_{(n)}\approx 1-1/n$, so that integral is something like $e^{-n^2}$, converging to $0$ very fast.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $X_{(n)}\rightarrow 1$ in probability. We also know that convergence in probability is conserved under continuous functions, so $f(X_{(n)})\rightarrow f(1)$ for any continuous function $f$ (in fact we only need continuity at $1$). As $f(x)=\int_x^1\frac{1}{\theta^n}e^{-(\theta-1)^{-2}}d\theta$ is continuous at 1 we have that $\mathbb{P}[f(X_{(n)})>C]\rightarrow \mathbb{P}[f(1)>C]=\mathbb{P}[0>C]=1_{C<0}$.